# How do you loop through a fetched API string and turn it into an <ul> in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

this is my first time connecting a C# backend Web API with a front end React app. My application has recipes with different properties. One of these properties being ingredients. I couldn't figure out how to seed it as a`List<string>` or a `string[]`, and so I had to just use a regular string. The one thing is- it's really long and messy as one would expect. I was wondering if there is a way to possibly loop through the `ingredients` property and turn it's contents into a `<ul>`? Any help would be appreciated- thanks!

Here is my Recipe.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


function Recipe(props) {
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <img src={props.recipeImage} alt='recipe photo' className='recipePicture'></img>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        <h3><strong>Category:</strong> {props.category}</h3>
        <h3><strong>Cuisine:</strong> {props.cuisine}</h3>
        <h4><strong>Ingredients:</strong> {props.ingredients}</h4>
        <h4><strong>Total Recipe Time:</strong> {props.time}</h4>
        <h4><strong>Yields:</strong> {props.makes}</h4>
        <h4><strong>Instructions:</strong> {props.instructions}</h4>  
    </React.Fragment>
    )
}

Recipe.propTypes = {
recipeImage: PropTypes.string,
name: PropTypes.string,
category: PropTypes.string,
cuisine: PropTypes.string,
ingredients: PropTypes.string,
time: PropTypes.string,
makes: PropTypes.number,
instructions: PropTypes.string,
recipeId: PropTypes.number
}

export default Recipe;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your API fetched data is an array with objects within it, you can make use of Array map() method to iterate each recipe name, category,ingredients and other properties.

This article will help you understand iteration of data in React.

> https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Create a parent component that maps the data and sends each property through the props in the Recipe component. Make sure to add recipe ID as key to the component.

```
  const  Parent=()=>{
    return (
        <div>

     {data.map((item)=>
           <Recipe key={item.recipeID}
             name={item.name}
             cuisine={item.cuisine}
             ingredients={item.ingredients}
             time={item.time}
             make={item.make}
             instructions={item.instructions}
          {/* and other data items  */}
             />
           )}
     </div>
    )
  }
```

Now you can use props in the child component.

```
 function Recipe(props) {
         return (
     <div>
       <img src={props.recipeImage} alt='recipe photo' 
             className='recipePicture'></img>
       <h1>{props.name}</h1>
       <h3><strong>Category:</strong> {props.category}</h3>
       <h3><strong>Cuisine:</strong> {props.cuisine}</h3>
       <h4><strong>Ingredients:</strong> {props.ingredients}</h4>
       <h4><strong>Total Recipe Time:</strong> {props.time}</h4>
       <h4><strong>Yields:</strong> {props.makes}</h4>
       <h4><strong>Instructions:</strong> {props.instructions}</h4>  
   </div>
 )
```

}

If you wish to loop through data and simply display it as list items, then you can simply code :

```
  const  Parent=()=>{
         return (
            <div>

        {data.map((item)=>
           <ul key={item.recipeID}>
             <li>{item.name}</li>
             <li>{item.cuisine}</li>
             <li>{item.ingredients}</li>
             <li>{item.time}</li>
             <li>{item.make}</li>
             <li>{item.instructions}</li>
          {/* and other data items  */}
             </ul>
           )}
     </div>
    )
  }
```

But for cleaner code, it is better to create a child component for display of items.